# Xcode warnings while compiling project

Tags: xcode, warnings, settings

I compile the project and see the following warnings

[image]

PortofolioBook is the previous project that I compiled. Could you tell me what this can be?

Thank You

Comment: You're making references to non-existing files inside your project. Have you checked your file structure (use finder) to make sure the files are in the correct place?

Comment: Thank you for info